# How to use more than one screen with Progress Openedge

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Is it possible to define on which screen a window appears?
I tried to find a solution, but all the time get only info about how to put somthing on screen or how to monitor a database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming this is classic ABL GUI.

The Window's position on the screen is determined by the X and Y attribute of the window. That is in pixel relative to the top/left corner of the "primary" screen.

You need to go to X < 0 (negative) if your default screen is the right one and you want to address the left monitor.

You can use the .NET System.Windows.Forms.Screens:AllScreens array to get details about the available monitors and their size and relative desktop positions:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE oScreens       AS System.Windows.Forms.Screen NO-UNDO EXTENT .
DEFINE VARIABLE iCount         AS INTEGER                     NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE i              AS INTEGER                     NO-UNDO.

/* Gets an array of all the screens connected to the system. */
ASSIGN oScreens       = System.Windows.Forms.Screen:AllScreens
       iCount         = EXTENT(oScreens) .

DO i = 1 TO iCount :
    MESSAGE "screen" i SKIP
            "Width"  oScreens[i]:Bounds:WIDTH    SKIP 
            "Height" oScreens[i]:Bounds:HEIGHT  SKIP 
            "X"      oScreens[i]:Bounds:X SKIP
            "Y"      oScreens[i]:Bounds:Y SKIP
        VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION BUTTONS OK.
END.
                    
DEFAULT-WINDOW:VISIBLE = TRUE . 

DEFAULT-WINDOW:X = -1000 . 

MESSAGE DEFAULT-WINDOW:X DEFAULT-WINDOW:Y .
```

For instance my left screen (center is primary) is 2560x1440 and starts with X = -2560.

So to have a window on it's top left corner, I set X to -2560 and Y to 0.

Comment: potential down-vote for ``view-as alert-box`` on the first but not the second ``message`` statement leaving me wondering where my focus had gone :-)

Comment: I like your sense of sarcasm ;)